# I am attempting to write some access SQL that will query a report and count the priority

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to this so please be patient
I am attempting to write some access SQL that will query a report and count the priority,
each row will have an Equipment number, priority, and a date.

What I would like to count is for each Equipment number that has a priority “Q” and the earliest date would = 1,  Next same equipment number with priority “Q” = 2, and  Next same equipment number with priority “Q” = 3
each time there is a new Equipment number then the count starts over with 1 
SQL that I have tried

```
SELECT SERVICES.*, (SELECT COUNT([PRIORITY]) FROM SVC WHERE SERVICES.ID=ID) And [SERVICES].[PRIORITY]="Q" AS Count1
FROM SVC AS SERVICES
ORDER BY SERVICES.ID;
```

This code produces and -1

[image: results]

[image: what the results should be]

Comment: Your current query references a field called `ID` which is not shown in your sample data - should the counts be grouped by `EQUIPMENT` or by `ID`?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is not taking `PLANDATE_MAINTCALL` into account:

```
SELECT S.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM SVC as S2
        WHERE S2.EQUIPEMENT = s.EQUIPMENT AND
              S2.PLANDATE_MAINTCALL <= S.PLANDATE_MAINTCALL AND
              S2.[PRIORITY] = "Q"
       ) AS Count1
FROM SVC AS S
ORDER BY S.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I used this and the answer it produces and a total number of 3 for each equipment number.  is there a way to have it count IE 1, 2 ,3

Comment: @Pat . . . Yes.  There was a typo in the query -- an unqualified column name.  I've fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
(SELECT COUNT([PRIORITY]) FROM SVC WHERE SERVICES.ID=ID) And [SERVICES].[PRIORITY]="Q"
```

contains 2 operands.
The 1st is:

```
(SELECT COUNT([PRIORITY]) FROM SVC WHERE SERVICES.ID=ID)
```

which returns an integer number and the 2nd is this:

```
[SERVICES].[PRIORITY]="Q"
```

which is boolean and returns `-1` for `True` or `0` for `False`.
So what you are doing is applying the operator `AND` on the results of these expressions and the final result is a boolean value: `-1` for `True` or `0` for `False`.
I suspect that what you want is this:

```
SELECT SERVICES.*, 
  (SELECT COUNT([PRIORITY]) FROM SVC WHERE SERVICES.ID=ID) AS Count1
WHERE [SERVICES].[PRIORITY]="Q" 
FROM SVC AS SERVICES
ORDER BY SERVICES.ID;
```

or:

```
SELECT SERVICES.*, 
  (SELECT COUNT([PRIORITY]) FROM SVC WHERE SERVICES.ID=ID AND [SERVICES].[PRIORITY]="Q") AS Count1
FROM SVC AS SERVICES
ORDER BY SERVICES.ID;
```

Although without sample data it's hard to tell.